# loop with skipped values....or is there a vectorized way to get weekly std dev from daily data?

Tags: r

I have a matrix of 5 day return data (the dataset skips weekends).  I want to create a new matrix with the standard deviation of the previous 52 weeks.  This requires me to select 52 values from the 5 day return data (which I call lrets5) by taking the current value, and then skipping backwards 5 values for each of the 52 weeks.

I want a new value of 52 week standard deviation for each day.

I can use seq() to find which rows I want to compute the standard deviation on, but I haven't figured out a good way to pull these values from lrets5 to compute the standard deviation.

This is my latest attempt:

```
weeklysd <- matrix(nrow=(nrow(lrets5)),ncol=20)  #pre allocate matrix 

for (i in 2:21){          #skip the date column
  x <- numeric()
  vec <- (as.numeric(lrets5[,i]))
  for (i in 256:nrow(lrets5)){
    v52 <- seq(from = i, to = (i-255), by = -5)
    x <- as.numeric(sd(vec[v52]))
  }
       weeklysd[,(k-1)] <- x
}
```

Should I be doing this in a loop or is there a vectorized way to do it?  Any help is much appreciated.

Here is a sample of the 5 day returns data that I want to pull values from:

```
 CDATE      ALLIANZ         BASF        BAYER         BMW     COBANK    
[1,]    NA  0.060130184  0.056995481  0.061607809  0.03391164 0.07898841    
[2,]    NA  0.055937306  0.019746763  0.025724891  0.02480198 0.06130053     
[3,]    NA  0.004089985  0.002836881  0.012861914 -0.02866390 0.04248100     
[4,]    NA -0.013072082 -0.002805051  0.003189795 -0.01123940 0.04879016     
[5,]    NA -0.019980685 -0.022409901 -0.025479085 -0.01384207 0.01969625
```

All weekdays are included in the dataset, even if it was a holiday in which the market was
closed.  I am just interested in computing the standard deviation of the previous 52 weekly returns, ignoring the fact that sometimes there weren't 5 days of trading within a given week.

Comment: Consider a combination of `period.apply` and `endpoints` functions from xts package.

Comment: `tapply` with `INDEX = format(date, "%U")` . Or if they really are not dates then just `%/% 5`(division modulo 5), but I would think that holiday weeks would make that prone to error. (You would get a better answer if you posted an appropriately complex dataset.

Comment: @DWin, I just added some sample data.  I'm reading the documentation on the xts package now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  I generated the row numbers I needed with seq() and stored the values in a list.

```
weeklylist <- list() 
 x <- numeric()
for (i in 256:nrow(lrets5)){         
  x <- numeric()
  x <- seq(from = i, to = (i-255), by = -5)      #generates the 52 row numbers
  weeklylist[[i]] <- x       
  }

#-----------------------


weeklyvol <- matrix(nrow=(nrow(lrets5)),ncol=20)   

for (i in 2:21){          
  abc <- numeric()
  for (j in 256:nrow(lrets5)){
      x <- as.vector(weeklylist[[j]])
      abc <- sd(lrets5[(x[1:52]),i])

      weeklyvol[j,(i-1)] <- abc *sqrt(52)     #multiply by sqrt(52) to get volatility
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use aggregate on what looks like a matrix,  it might be just

```
aggregate(mtx[,-1], 
          cut(1:nrow(mtx), seq(0,nrow(mtx)+4,by=5), right=TRUE, include.lowest=TRUE),
          sd)
```

With the data columns you used I get:

```
 aggregate(mtx, 
           list(wk=cut(1:nrow(mtx), seq(0,nrow(mtx)+4,by=5), right=TRUE, include.lowest=TRUE)),
           sd)
#--------
     wk    ALLIANZ       BASF      BAYER        BMW     COBANK
1 [0,5] 0.03812483 0.02985568 0.03189135 0.02692465 0.02204558
```